# How to make a list accept /n so that when writen to a file so that not everyting is on the same line?

Tags: python, string, join

So this is my code for a random serial number generator and i can't figure out how to make each serial number appear on a different line at the moment they have only got spaces between them how do i make them appear on a new line?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random, hashlib, os
from sys import exit
from time import sleep
database_check1 = os.path.expanduser('~/Codemaker/database.txt')
codemaker_dir_check1 = os.path.expanduser('~/Codemaker')
database_check = os.path.isfile(database_check1)
codemaker_dir_check = os.path.isdir(codemaker_dir_check1)

if codemaker_dir_check == True:
    pass
else:
    os.system('mkdir ~/Codemaker')

def choice():

    if database_check == True:
        replace_or_no = raw_input('Warning database.txt already exists   do   you want to relace it? y = yes n=no a = add more to end of file.       y/n/a?:   ')
        if replace_or_no == ('y'):
            os.system('rm ~/Codemaker/database.txt')
            os.system('> ~/Codemaker/database.txt')              

        elif replace_or_no == ('a'):
            pass
        elif replace_or_no == ('n'):
            print('We did not change the database :)')
            exit()

        else:
            print('An error has occured you probably pressed the wrong         button     if you wish to try again it should work')
            exit()
    else:
        os.system('> ~/Codemaker/database.txt')

Acceptable_letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
gencodelist = []
choice()
database_file_append1 = os.path.expanduser('~/Codemaker/database.txt')
database_file_append = open(database_file_append1, 'a')



def gencode():
    for i in ('hih'):
        for i in ('hihi'):
            gencodelist.append(random.choice(Acceptable_letters))

        gencodelist.append('-')
    for i in ('hihi'):
        gencodelist.append(random.choice(Acceptable_letters))

    gencodelist.append(' ')

for x in xrange(0, 100):
    gencode()
    gencodeout = ''.join(gencodelist)
    print(gencodeout)
    database_file_append.write(gencodeout)
message = ['100 codes have generated and been written to database.txt  located  in ', database_file_append1, '! :)']
finalmessage = "".join(message)
print(finalmessage)
```

Comment: Maybe just do this after you write a serial number `database_file_append.write('\n')` ?

Comment: I can see major bugs in your current logic that I would suggest addressing before you consider adjusting unimportant things such as how it prints/writes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
gencodelist.append(' ')
```

with

```
gencodelist.append('\n')
```

It is working after this code change.

Comment: You can replace print(gencodeout) with print(gencodeout.replace("\n"," ")) to keep the print with spaces...but this wont impact your file..The file content will still come in new lines.

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'` is used to create a space in between two lines and `'\r'` is used to emulate a enter or return keypress. it can be appended, joined, etc... to any string in the following ways. `my_str+='\n'`, `'\n'.join(my_list)`, ''.join(str(x)+'\n' for x in my_list)` and more. what problem are you having?